# Systemd Service ExecStart command too long

Tags: systemd

I have following Service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Watch Bovon Handyhalterung
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Documents/bin/amazon-pricewatcher -url="https://www.amazon.de/Bovon-Handyhalterung-Verstellbarer-Handyhalter-360%C2%B0Rotation-Schwarz/dp/B077GNWNL8?pf_rd_p=0f6687bc-b0cb-44d9-9696-138c1879ad4f&pd_rd_wg=e0fEm&pf_rd_r=CA5EYTP96QYVH336GFFR&ref_=pd_gw_cr_simh&pd_rd_w=xOczT&pd_rd_r=ee8c3a4d-3220-417a-bccf-435aaf791d61" -email="tobiwimma04@gmail.com"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It says it failed due to bad setting.
If I use a shorter url flag, it works, so I assumed that the url flag is too long (maybe this makes the command too long)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the shortened URL also contain `%` sequences (like the `%C` appearing in your example)? I wonder if it's the presence of those (rather than the length) that's the problem

Comment: No it didn't. It might really be the problem. But how can I fix this?

Comment: You could try replacing `%` in the URI by `%%` as described in the `Specifiers` section of the [systemd.unit manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers)

Comment: Or try using single quotes around the URL instead of double quotes.

Comment: Now it works, thank you!